# Mongoid Class Definition Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a mongo document called location:

```
class Location < MongoDocument                      
  field :latitude, type: Float             
  field :longitude, type: Float            
end
```

MongoDocument is as such:

```
class MongoDocument
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
end
```

Whilst within another mongo document I have a method:

```
def self.local(location, limit_results)
    if location.present? && location.latitude.present?
    #run some code
    end
end
```

In debug I can inspect location and it recognises the object and will show my the hash of its contents:

```
{Location}#<Location:0x6fa5798>
@_id = {BSON::ObjectId}512b2330b109ab17fc00002c
@latitude = nil
@longitude = nil
```

If I try to use any selector (getter/setter) on this object it returns:
    `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

I have tried:

```
location[:id]
location['id']
location.id
location[:latitude]
location['latitude']
location.latitude
location[:longitude]
location['longitude']
location.longitude
```

Any clues? I am midway through migrating my code from mongomapper to mongoid, and am stumped by this.

Answer (score 0):

I also forgot to mention that the location that was being passed in was from 'new' rather than 'create'. Swapping it to a create fixed my issue.